# How can i make the QSlider indicate the current value

Tags: c++, qt

I can't figure out from the QT Assistant how to set the `QSlider` to show the current value while dragging, I came with this idea initially:

```
QLabel* lblYear = new QLabel();
QSlider* sldYear = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);

QObject::connect(sldYear, &QSlider::valueChanged, [&]() {
    lblYear->setText(sldYear->value);
});
```

But it doesn't work:

```
'QAbstractSlider::value': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I don't know if the label idea is ok, and I don't mind changing it. The only requirement is to see the value of the slider at any time.

Comment: `pointer to remember`? Are you sure you post the actual error?

Comment: Yep, i found the problem, instead of ```lblYear->setText(sldYear->value);``` , i had to use ```lblYear->setText(QString::fromStdString(std::to_string(sldYear->value())));```

Comment: That doesn't sound correct at all, why would you convert to std string only to convert back to QString?

Comment: sldYear->value() returns int, std::to_string converts it to std::string, and then QString::fromStdString converts it to QString , because that's what qlabel uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QObject::connect(sldYear, &QSlider::valueChanged, [](int value) {
    lblYear->setText(QString::number(value));
});
```

You need to convert `int` value to `QString` to be able to use it with `setText`. Also, capturing pointer by reference is not always safe and it also doesn't make sense, since it is as cheap as capture it by value. Moreover, in this case you don't even need to, you get the `value` from the signal interface.